# Is there a way to force some block caching despite system block caching option is disabled?

Tags: 7, caching, performance

In `/admin/config/development/performance` settings page, my "cache blocks" options is disabled due to "Block caching is inactive because you have enabled modules defining content access restrictions."

But I absolutely need to globally cache some blocks (in particular some superfish blocks because they recreates menu items on every page load if not cached).

I've already tried [Block Cache Alter](https://drupal.org/project/blockcache_alter) module, but without success, probably because this module can works only if system "cache block" option is enabled (see: https://drupal.org/node/1954224 )

Thank you for help

Answer (score 7):

With latest Drupal 7.33 release there is a new setting variable now:

```
/**
 * Block caching:
 *
 * Block caching may not be compatible with node access modules depending on
 * how the original block cache policy is defined by the module that provides
 * the block. By default, Drupal therefore disables block caching when one or
 * more modules implement hook_node_grants(). If you consider block caching to
 * be safe on your site and want to bypass this restriction, uncomment the line
 * below.
 */

$conf['block_cache_bypass_node_grants'] = TRUE;
```

Setting the above to TRUE the "cache blocks" option becomes checkable.

Answer (score 3):

[block_form_system_performance_settings_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/block_form_system_performance_settings_alter/7) is where that code lives. Looking into it you can force this by running `variable_set('block_cache', TRUE);` once or by adding `$conf['block_cache'] = TRUE;` to your settings.php file (near the bottom). I would opt for the settings.php method.

Core Issue for this as well: https://drupal.org/node/1930960 (Now in 7.33). See MXT's answer on how to use it.

Note that by doing this bad things might happen. You have been warned.